# Unity IAP, When i click on the purchase button, nothing happens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to implement the subscription option in my game using Unity IAP, setting up buttons and a catalog, I upload my application to a closed google console test, after installing it on my phone, pressing the purchase button nothing happens, how do I understand what the problem is?

IAP Catalog are configured, Unity IAP and Unity gaming services are automatically initialised
[Unity IAP Catalog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHmcu.png)

UPD:
This for IAPListener

```
public void OnPurchaseCompleted(Product product)
    {
        switch (product.definition.id)
        {
            case "yearly-premium":
                Invoke("ActivateSubscription",0.1f);
                break;
            case "monthly-premium":
                Invoke("ActivateSubscription",0.1f);
                break;
        }
    }
```

UPD2: or this in iap button

```
    public void ActivateSubscription()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Subscription",1);
        PurchaseWindowState(false);
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the source code of your button?

Comment: @PavlosMavris Added to UPD

Comment: In unity editor, all works fine, but not on android device

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Logcat for debugging. or can use unity asset store tools like [InGameDebugConsole](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/in-game-debug-console-68068) to check log in device also.

Comment: Can I use this, after publishing app in closed test in google console?

Comment: Yes, you can use it